# Pass DateTime2 parameter value using ISqlQuery

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, sqldatetime, isqlquery

I am using the `ISqlQuery` interface of Nhibernate to fire a SQL query on database. Following is the scenario. My Domain Model has a property:

```
public virtual Datetime StartTime { get; set; }
```

The database has a column `StartTime` of type `DateTime2`.

I have added `UserTypeConvention` for mapping code's Datetime to DB's DateTime2 and it works fine.

But when I try to query using ISqlQuery then I'm not able to set parameters to that query with the type DateTime2. If I use ISqlQuery.SetDateTime then by default it maps to DB's Datetime type and gives an exception 'SqlDateTime overflow Must be between 1 1 1753 12 00 00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM'.

I tried to use `ISqlQuery.SetParameter("propname",datetimevalue,Nhibernate.IType)` but I couldn't find `NHibernate.IType` implementation for DateTime2.

Any support for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NHibernateUtil.DateTime2`